# Remove autolayout (constraints) in Interface Builder using xCode 4.2

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, xcode4.2, xcode4.5

I had created a project in xcode 4.5 But now I have xcode 4.2, in Xcode 4.2 I am unable to open the project's nib files. when I click on nib file, it show following error message.

[image]

Comment: maybe try turning off auto-layout in the 4.5 project before attempting to open it in 4.2? It might work but then again you cannot really expect an older version of Xcode to open a newer version project cleanly.

Comment: but I really dont have the xcode 4.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

go in xib-->showfileInspectore ->

[image]

uncheck use autolayout lik below image

[image]